# Jasmine not loading vendor options

Tags: jquery, testing, gruntjs, jasmine, bower

I'm trying to set up a sample Jasmine app, but it seems I've made a mistake while including jQuery.
My Gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        jasmine: {
            src: 'src/**/*.js',
            specs: 'spec/**/*.js',
            options: {
                vendor: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-runner');


    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'jasmine');

};
```

I have a spec file, which references `$` somewhere, which will fail with this message:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/spec/PlayerSpec.js:14
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/node_modules/grunt-jasmine-runner/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1035
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/node_modules/grunt-jasmine-runner/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2034
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/node_modules/grunt-jasmine-runner/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2024
```

The path to jquery.js is definitely correct. If I remove the `$` reference, the spec passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem is that `grunt-jasmine-runner` has no support for `grunt` 0.4+, and it has no `vendor` option. Instead use the more current `grunt-contrib-jasmine` that works with `grunt` 0.4+

Comment: The path is definitely correct (running it with an external path doesn't work, either). I think my mistake was not adding `jquery.js` to `src`. If I move `specs` to `options`, no specs are executed at all anymore: "0 specs, 0 failures in 0s."

Comment: It's really strange, you are using the basic configuration :( . What happens if you put your vendor as a array instead of string?

Comment: Same thing...  I'm using this sample project https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-jasmine-runner-example, which works fine out of the box (even though `spec` isn't inside `options` here either). As soon as I reference `$`, though, the spec fails.

Comment: grunt-jasmine-runner has no support for grunt 0.4+: https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-runner . I recommend you to install grunt-jasmine and put my configuration.

Comment: Also I saw that grunt-jasmine-runner has no vendor options. This is the reason of the problem.